# Gradle plugin extension set a property of type Map

Tags: java, gradle-plugin

I want to set a Map of attributes to my plugin extension. So basically I want to write something like

```
settings {
  envVars = {
    a = "abc"
    b = "dec"
    ...
    n = "sdf"
  }
}
```

When I use an attribute in my Extension class

```
private Map<?,?> envVars;
```

Gradle tells me that it can not set the property settings. So what I would like to achieve is to set a map of values in my extension class.

What I did achieve is to get the closure when i write the following:

```
settings {
  envVars {
    a = "abc"
    b = "dec"
    ...
    n = "sdf"
  }
}

public class extension {
....
    public envVars(Closure c){}
}
```

But then I have no clue what to do with the closure and how to access what is inside, so I would rather have a Map instead of the closure

Regards
Mathias

Answer (score 6):

Ok, you just have to write the map properly :/

```
envVars = [test: 'test']
```

and everything is fine

Comment: This should be marked as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following to read a map of values from build.gradle

reference: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin

**Container class:**

```
class Database {
  def name
  def arguments = [logLevel: 'info']

  Database(String name) {
    this.name = name
  }
```

**Extension Class:**

```
class MyExtension {
  final NamedDomainObjectContainer<Database> databases
  def databases(Closure closure){
    databases.configure(closure)
  }

  def methodMissing(String name, args) {
    arguments[name] = args[0]
  }
}
```

**Load Extensions**

```
  def databases = project.container(Database) { name ->
      new Database(name)
    }
  project.configure(project) {
      extensions.create("extensionName", MyExtension, databases)
  }
```

**Sample build.gradle:**

```
dbDiff{
  databases{
    db1{
      url  'testUrl'
    }
   }
 }
```